# Non-blocking retries with Spring Kafka batch consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka 2.8.0 and I'm trying to implement [non-blocking retries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0/reference/html/#using-the-retryabletopic-annotation) for [batch kafka consumer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0/reference/html/#batch-listeners). Here are my config and consumer:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, GenericRecord>> 
            batchListenerFactory(ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class MyConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "my-topic",
            containerFactory = "batchListenerFactory"
    )
    @RetryableTopic(
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
            attempts = "4",
            topicSuffixingStrategy = SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
            autoCreateTopics = "false"
    )
    public void consume(List<ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord>> messages) {
        // do some stuff
    }

}
```

But on sturtup I'm getting the following exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided class BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter is not assignable from AcknowledgingConsumerAwareMessageListener`

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to combine batch consumer with `@RetryableTopic`?
2. Is there any another way to implement non-blocking retries for batch consumer? Is it possible to use `RetryTemplate` for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@RetryableTopic` is not supported with batch listeners.

The `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` (`DefaultErrorHandler` for 2.8 and later) supports sending a failed record within a batch to a dead letter topic, with the help of the listener throwing a `BatchListenerFailedException` indicating which record failed.

You would then have to implement your own listener on that topic.