# @RetryableTopic with multiple kafkaListenerContainerFactory not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

The original kafkaListenerContainerFactory in the application is set as a batchListner and because of this @RetryableTopic is not working (which I understood is [normal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70672453/1889512)), so I created a second factory, without setting it as a batchListner and I've set it as the listenerContainerFactory inside the RetryConsumer. But the error still persist:

```
The provided class FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter is not assignable from MessageListener: 
class org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter\
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory
      (
          MessageConverter messageConverter
      ) {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

    factory.setBatchListener(false);
    factory.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    factory.setCommonErrorHandler(defaultErrorHandler());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(generateConsumerConfig()));
    factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(consumerRecord -> {
      if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(kafkaProperties.getConsumer().getLogPayload())) {
        log.info(consumerRecord.toString());
      }
      return false;
    });

    return factory;
  }
```

My RetryConsumer looks like this

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class RetryConsumer {

  LocalDateTime now;


  @RetryableTopic(

      attempts = "5",
      autoCreateTopics = "false",
      backoff = @Backoff(30_000),
      fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC,
      listenerContainerFactory = "retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
  )
  @KafkaListener(id = "retry-consumer",
                 topics = "topic1",
                 containerFactory = "retryKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void handleMessage (
      String message,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic
  ) {

    log.info("Received message: {} from topic: {}", message, topic);
    if (now == null) {
      now = LocalDateTime.now();
      System.out.println("attempt at:" + now.toString());
    } else {
      System.out.println("minutes between attempts:" + Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), now).toSeconds());
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Test exception");
  }


  @DltHandler
  public void handleDlt (
      String message,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic
  ) {

    log.info("Message: {} handled by dlq topic: {}", message, topic);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any chance to have a simple project from you to reproduce, please?

Comment: hi @ArtemBilan here it is https://github.com/objectivePinta/retry-kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `FirstTopicListener` with a `@KafkaListener(topics = "first-topic")`.

Then you have `RetryTopicConfiguration myRetryTopic` which by default configures a retry topic for an original one. And in this case it does fail to do that because there is no compatibility with batch listener and retry topic feature.

Add this `.excludeTopic("first-topic")` to your `RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder` to fix this problem.

You may raise a GitHub issue, so we may revise the logic to show more info about such a rejection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess if I want retryTopic for only one topic, and for the rest not, I can use         .includeTopics(List.of("my-retry-topic")), right?

Comment: That's correct. But at the same time you need to think if you really need that custom `RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder`  at all... Probably `@RetryableTopic` is enough.

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to have only a retry topic and a dlt topic, so no main topic? Or the retry topic to be the main topic as well? As I pass to the retry topic only some messages which I expect to be valid in the future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, cannot tell you: I'm not so good with that feature. See if docs have some hint for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic